# c# combobox, combobox-y нужно вывести один столбец из БД

Tags: c#

winforms приложение, combobox-y в коллекциях нужно вывести один столбец из базы данных. сам пробовал по многочисленным исходникам, что-то получилось вывести в combobox. при щелчке на один из выведенных элементов данные в combobox увеличиваются в два раза. пробовал combobox1.Items.Clear(); тогда вообще данные не выбираются. помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
private void LoadData()  // метод вывода на combobox
    {
        
        con.Open();
        var command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT dslam FROM Sumdslam";
        
       // con.Close();
        var adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i ++)
         {
             combobox1.Items.Add(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

             con.Close();

         }
      private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        //   combobox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
       
        LoadData();
          
     
        // combobox1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если очистить содержимое combobox1 через clear тогда строка не выбирается вообще , тоесть я должен выбирать один элемент оттуда со всеми данными введенными выше должно добавляется. если не очищать содержимое  combobox  тогда происходит задвоение.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то сейчас метод LoadData у Вас вызывается каждый раз при изменении выбранного элемента в Combobox- отсюда и задвоения. Строчка combobox1.Items.Clear(); должна находиться перед вызовом метода LoadData. При заполнении списка вы закрываете подключение к БД после обращении к первому значению в БД, перенесите con.Close(); за пределы цикла- когда цикл завершает свою работу.

Comment: да, LoadData вызывается при изменении другой таблицы баз данных.  если очистить содержимое combobox ничего из выбираться просто

Comment: У Вас очистка Combobox происходит после вызова LoadData, сделайте очистку перед тем как вызвать метод заполнения.

Comment: сделал , ничего не меняется , раздвоение не происходит но и нельзя выбирать элемент из combobox. странно , почему так происходит ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  
}
```

оказывается ничего не надо было передать в combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged. не знаю почему но все работает.